# What equipment would an attacker need to infect a SIM card?

Tags: exploit, virus, phone, simcard

I'm aware that SIM cards can store malware according to this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121571/can-a-sim-card-propagate-malware) but what equipment would be needed to do such an attack? For example, would you need a Computer and a SIM card reader or could it get infected from a normal Android phone?

Comment: a [sim-card writer](https://www.wise-geek.com/what-is-a-sim-writer.htm) perhaps? And a computer of course.